# How can I get all content within <td> tag using a HTML Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

So I'm writing an application that will do a little screen scraping. I'm using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to load an entire HTML page into an instance of `HtmlDocoument` called `doc`. Now I want to parse that doc, looking for this:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="3">
<tr><td>First rows stuff</td></tr>
<tr>
<td> 
The data I want is in here <br /> 
and it's seperated by these annoying <br /> 's.

No id's, classes, or even a single <p> tag. </p> Just a bunch of <br />  tags.
</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

So I just need to get the data within the 2nd row. How can I do this? Should I use a regex or something else?

**Update:** Here is how I'm loading my `doc`

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(Url);
```

Comment: Is there only one table in your document? If not, how will you locate the table you are interested in?

Comment: @Mark: Based on the `cellspacing="3"` attribute. I understand this sounds *hacky* (and thats because it is), but no other table in the 1000+ documents contains a cellspacing attribute at all. This isn't production code, just a project I'm running to collect some data.

Comment: Your title and question disagree. Title: `How can I get all content within <table></table> tags` Question: `So I just need to get the data within the 2nd row.` Which is it? Can you fix it so that the title and question match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) already I would suggest using the methods it provides to find the information you want. There are a few ways to navigate the document, but one of the most concise is to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). In this case you could use something like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("input.html");
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode
                   .SelectNodes("//table[@cellspacing='3']/tr[2]/td")
                   .Single();
string text = node.InnerText;
```

Comment: I think your on the right track, but I'm not seeing the `.Single()` method in intellisense. I'm using version 1.4.0 of the HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Add a reference to and use System.Data.Linq;

Comment: @Bob Dylan: That code was just an example. You don't *have* to use `Single()` if you don't have it available - you could just write `.SelectNodes(...)[0]` instead. Though knowing about Linq would be a huge asset for developing in C#.

Comment: @Mark: Ok I just tried using the `[0]` like you said and got an exception: `node`: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I assume this means it didn't find the table, tr, or the td?

Comment: @Bob Dylan: Correct. You could change the XPath expression to "//table[@cellspacing=3]" and see if that matches.

Comment: @Mark: I tried that and it gave me the same error. Also I've updated my answer to show how I'm loading the document (just in case that makes a difference).

Answer (score 1):

"Something else" is the best answer -- HTML is best parsed by an HTML parser rather than via regular expressions.  I'm no C# expert, but I hear the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is well-liked for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[I'd say som̡et̨hińg Else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Normally I would agree with that too, but I think this is an exception becuase I'm looking for something so narrow. However if you could **actully suggest something else** I would be open to that too.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably get better mileage with an xml parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Agility pack already, then it's just a matter of using some thing `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@cellspacing='3']")` to get the table in the document.  Try looking through the documentation and coding examples.  Since you already have structured data, it's rediculous to go back to the text data and reparse.